# Howto set auto counter in tcolorbox below

Tags: tcolorbox

```
\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{enhanced,
before skip=2mm,after skip=2mm,
colback=black!5,colframe=black!50,boxrule=0.2mm,
attach boxed title to top left={xshift=1cm,yshift*=1mm-\tcboxedtitleheight},
varwidth boxed title*=-3cm,
boxed title style={frame code={
\path[fill=tcbcolback!30!black]
([yshift=-1mm,xshift=-1mm]frame.north west)
arc[start angle=0,end angle=180,radius=1mm]
([yshift=-1mm,xshift=1mm]frame.north east)
arc[start angle=180,end angle=0,radius=1mm];
\path[left color=tcbcolback!60!black,right color=tcbcolback!60!black,
middle color=tcbcolback!80!black]
([xshift=-2mm]frame.north west) -- ([xshift=2mm]frame.north east)
[rounded corners=1mm]-- ([xshift=1mm,yshift=-1mm]frame.north east)
-- (frame.south east) -- (frame.south west)
-- ([xshift=-1mm,yshift=-1mm]frame.north west)
[sharp corners]-- cycle;
},interior engine=empty,
},
fonttitle=\bfseries,
title={#2},#1}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide]
(http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Please help us to help you also and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`